Why Navigation after WebAuthenticator in MAUI doesn't work
I'm building application on .NET MAUI what use "WebAuthenticator" to authenticate with Google. The Problem is that, after successful login, I'm not able to navigate to another page.
    [RelayCommand]
    private async Task OAuthLogin(string authProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            WebAuthenticatorResult authResult = await WebAuthenticator.AuthenticateAsync(
             new Uri($"https://ee33-31-13-238-188.ngrok-free.app/auth/{authProvider.ToLower()}/login"),
             new Uri("myapp://"));

            LoginResultModel result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<LoginResultModel>(Uri.UnescapeDataString(authResult.Get("loginResult")));

            if (result.Code == (int)GeneralStatusEnum.Success)
            {
                App.UserId = result.User.Id;
                App.JwtToken = result.Jwt;
                App.UserName = result.User.FirstName;
                App.Email = result.User.Email;


                MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
                {
                    await Navigation.PushAsync<HomePage>();

                });

                //await Navigation.PushAsync<HomePage>();

            }
            else
            {
                if (result.Message == MessageConstants.Unsuccess)
                {
                    throw new Exception(MessageConstants.GeneralError);
                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception(result.Message);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException ex)
        {
            await App.DisplayAlert(App.MESSAGE_HEADER_ERROR, ex.Message, App.MESSAGE_OK);
        }
    }

Tested to invoke the navigation on "Main Thread" but it still don't work, I can see the "Navigation" is not null.
 MainThread.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
    {
         await Navigation.PushAsync<HomePage>();

    });

Second test what I did was, to add "await Task.Delay(100);" and this way, the Navigation works as exptected. If someone have idea what can cause the Navigation to doesn't work, please share.
This is my configuration in "App.xaml.cs"
LoginPageViewModel vm = new LoginPageViewModel(authSer, oAuthSer);
var page = new LoginPage(vm);
MainPage = new NavigationPage(page);

I'm not getting any errors, when debugging, i saw that code what Navigates to "Home Page" is invoked, before the browser to be completely closed.

"doesn't work" ??? can you be more specific? Like what's happening is it crashing ? An error log?

Sorry for that. I mean, nothing happens. I'm returned back to my login page after successful login. No errors. I saw that, when  my code for Navigating is executed, seems browser is still not completely closed.

The problem was in some of these packages versions:
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Essentials" Version="8.0.7" />

I updated them all to the latest at once, this is the reason why I'm not sure exactly at which is the problem.

As you mentioned

Navigating is executed, seems browser is still not completely closed.

By the time redirection to your app is done, the Navigation call is being executed.
Simple solution would be adding a await Task.Delay() to give time for user to return back to app window.
If you want more ideal solution, you can define a boolean property in your LoginPage Vm and set it's value in OnAppearing() and OnDisappearing() of LoginPage
public class LoginPageViewModel
{
   public bool IsPageVisible
   {
     get => _isPageVisible;
     set
     {           
           _isPageVisible = value;
     }
 }

In LoginPage.xaml.cs
 protected override void OnAppearing()
 {
     base.OnAppearing();
     vm.IsPageVisible = true;
 }

 protected override void OnDisappearing() 
 {
     base.OnDisappearing();
     vm.IsPageVisible = false;
 }

And after Authenticaiton call you can wait until the page appears back.

        // Wait until the page is visible before navigating
        while (!IsPageVisible)
        {
            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
        await Navigation.PushAsync<HomePage>();


"By the time redirection to your app is done, the Navigation call is being executed."
That i don't think is right, because in the response i have all the data available before navigation. Thank you for your response. But that solution seems not good. I can't understand why i have to delay when already i have all the data. The navigation is there. Something prevent me to do the navigation.

I'm absolutely newbie in mobile development, these delays looks awful to see in code, absolutely and easily can be misunderstood when someone read the code.

@furybg can you provide what's happening in Homepage constructor?

@furybg Wait !!! Navigation.PushAsync<HomePage>();  is this a custom method ???

No, that comes from Maui.Plugins.PageResolver.

can you check navigating using normal NavigationPage naviagtion and check if the issue is still there? Ex: await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new HomePage());

I tried to do this: await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync();
And the problem is still there. The reason why i don't want to use new HomePage() is because i have to provide many different services into

@furybg I think you used same method from that Plugin again... Just try navigating to new dummy page by intializing new DummyPage() and passsing it as parameter and check if it's working, Then we  will know if there issue with the Plugin method

Alright thanks for the idea should report the result soon!

Okay, no change

UPDATE: In Live Visual Tree i can see my HomePage is added, but when i hover with the mouse over, I'm getting this error: "MauiContext should have been set on parent."

@furybg You are testing in which platform? iOS?

Tested on Android, you can see the Accepted answer, i was able to solve this.
